# Apache commons FileUtils cannot access NAS directory in linux

Tags: java, linux, apache-commons, nas

We have NAS dir mounted on linux box where out java application runs in application server. Now when I logged in to this linux box then i can clearly see that NAS dir mount "/data" has all permission RWX at all level but when my program runs then it throws exception that "Destination '/data/test' directory cannot be created". But I can clearly see that dir with all permission. I am using apache commons FileUtils to copy file from one local dir to NAS server dir somthing like this

```
FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(srcFile, destDir, true);
```

Comment: Does the /test directory exist?

Comment: Yes it does and it has all permission to copy source file. Also Fileut I'll copy method creates all directory if it does not exist.

Comment: And what user does the java application server run as?

Comment: It is running with weblogic user ans this is webapp deployed in weblogic.

Comment: What user do you log in as to check the permissions? The only thing that makes sense us that the weblogic user lacks the necessary permissions.

Comment: I logged in as a different user, kind of super user. But permission on "/data" folder is "rwx rwx rwx", that means weblogic user has permission to read, write and execute on that folder. Correct? Or Am i missing anything?